# How do I render an array of form elements in Zend Framework 1.12?

Tags: php, zend-framework

So I have an array of elements like so:

```
$this->addElement(new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('activity_' . $activityModel->id, array(
    'value' => $somevalue,
    'ignore' => true,
    'decorators'    => array('ViewHelper')
)));
```

Where $this is an extension of the Zend_Form class. I am using a custom view script. How do I render this array? Currently I tried:

```
<?php echo $this->element->activity_fanpage_count; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Zend_Form has a __toString() method. So you can simply echo your form. Same with the elements and display groups.

First you need to assign your form to a view variable in the controller. Then you can access it from your template with `$this->form`